# Software Protection service fails to start

Tags: windows-activation, windows-services

Software Protection service fails to start with error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. One of the effects of this issue is that Windows is not activated now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the corrupted file %windir%\System32\sppsvc.exe.

It has been fixed by executing sfc /scannow.